# Convert JSON to XML to pass to FillXfaForm

Tags: c#, json, xml, itext7

I want to convert my JSON object to XML to use in the FillXfaForm to populate my pdf form using iText.

```
public void PopulatePDF(String src, string jsonString, String dest) 
{
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
     XfaForm xfa = form.GetXfaForm();
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonString, "root");
    String xmlString = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
    xfa.FillXfaForm(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)));
    xfa.Write(pdf);
    pdf.Close();
}
```

It's giving me an error "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in itext.forms.dll but was not handled in user code". It's giving an error on the line  xfa.FillXfaForm(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString))).

JSON string is as follows:

```
{ "id": 278,  "clientID": 0,  "Number": null  "Amount": 0.0 }
```

resulting XML string is as follows:

```
<root><id>278</id><clientID>0</clientID><Number /><Amount>0</Amount></root>
```

Here's a link to the form: (it has one field called id) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dkb4ry5gu8m74e/TestForm.pdf?dl=0

Comment: What does the JSON look like, and what does the resulting XML look like?

Comment: @MichaelKay added the JSON and the XML

Comment: Then I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Hi, can you attach your form?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I added a link to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form in your PDF document is not an XFA form. It is a plain AcroForm. `XfaForm#FillXfaForm` only works with XFA forms.

In order to fill a plain field in AcroForm, you have to know the names of its fields. For instance, in the document you attached, there is a field with `id` name.

This code fills `id` field with `278` value:

```
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
form.GetField("id").SetValue("278");
```

Of course, you will have to deal with parsing XML/JSON yourself.